# Disable border for last element when element types differ

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to disable the border for the last element when the element types differ, ie. one is a paragraph and another is a hyperlink?

http://jsfiddle.net/e4zjcmue/

`div *:last-of-type:after { border-right: none; }` unfortunately disables all borders.

```css
div * {
  display: inline;
}

div *:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

div *:last-of-type:after {
  /* border-right: none; */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector that you seem to be looking for is `:last-child` and not `last-of-type`.

The `*:last-of-type` selector selects the last element of every single type under the parent. That is, it would select the last `div`, the last `p` etc. In your snippet, the first element is also the last element of its type and hence all the borders disappear.

The `:last-child` however selects only the last child element of the parent and hence removes the border only from the `a` tag in this instance. The `*` before `:last-child` is not mandatory because the selector by default selects the last child element irrespective of its type.

```css
div * {
  display: inline;
}
div *:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
div :last-child:after {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pseudo selector [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child) instead, as demonstrated:

```css
div * {
  display: inline;
}
div *:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
div *:last-child:after {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily accomplish that by adding html 'id' attribute.

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <a id="last" href="#">Ipsum</a>
</div>

#last { border: 0; color: #000;
```